# PHP retrieving content of database

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have a database with a few tables in it. The table i'm working on has 6 columns in it,

`school_id, title, location, content, class_date and user_id`

The school_id is unique (ranging from 1-20) and there are 4 different user_id (ranging from 1-4).....I'm working on a site which has a table that displays the information about the user and it's correspondence. I have a ReadMore link in the last column of the displayed table, my question is this, when I click the ReadMore link I want it to display the content field in the database based on which event is clicked.

### For the login, the user is asked their user_id as their password.

```
//$T is called from a previous page which is the user_id or the password
$T = $_SESSION["ID"];


$INFO= $dbc->query("SELECT content FROM events where school_id='$T'");
$a = $INFO->fetch();


$b = $a['content'];
print_r($b);
```

THE ABOVE CODE IS HOW I TRY TO PRINT OUT THE CORRECT CONTENT BUT ONLY THE FIRST INSTANCE IS PRINTED OUT

THE BELOW CODE IS HOW THE TABLE IS DISPALYED ON MY SITE

```
<?php
$gold= $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE user_id='$idcheck' ORDER BY     event_dateLIMIT 10");
    $x = $gold->fetchAll();

    echo "<table border = '1'>";
    echo "<tr>
         <td> Event </td>
         <td> Date of Event </td>
         <td> Location </td>
         <td> Event Information</td>
         </tr>";

    foreach ($r as $back) {
        $title = $back['title'];
        $eventdate = $back['class_date'];
        $location = $back['location'];

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$title</td>";
        echo "<td>$eventdate</td>";
        echo "<td>$location</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        ?>
<form action="displaycontent.php" method="post"> 

            <input type="submit" value="Read More">
        </form>
        <?php
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Not too sure I understand what you are trying to do here... When you click the Read More link, what is supposed to happen? It would appear you are re-directing to displaycontent.php but what is on this page? Just the content and nothing more or what? How does your PHP script know which content to display?

Comment: Yes peter, when the ReadMore link is clicked, I want it to display the value of the 'content' field. But with the code I'm using now when I click it, it displays the first content with the password(user_id)...for example, when I click the 3rd read more link or the 5th link, it still displays the first content because it matches it to the user_id not the event_id

Comment: Are you submitting any information with your form? Say a hidden field like `<input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="$back['event_id']" />` which you could then hook onto using `$_POST['event_id']`? Without seeing how its structured I'm not sure exactly how you would do it..

Comment: No i'm not submitting anything with the form, it's only there to generate the ReadMore link if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

fetch method returns next found row from your statement. You have to iterate over your result to get all rows.

Something like

```
while ($row = $INFO->fetch()) {
    $b[] = $row;
}
```

Then have a look at print_r($b). It should look like

```
array(0=>array('content'=>'Some content1'),
      1=>array('content'=>'Some content2'), ....)
```

And your way of outputting the result should work.